# Dynamic pivot - doesnt read the '+' sign

Tags: sql

Hi I am trying to run the below code, but getting the error below. telling me that the issue is due to ' + @Cols + ', however this code is referenced from the forums. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Error
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 27
Incorrect syntax near ' + @Cols + '.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(year) 
            FROM [Reporting].[dbo].[FX_Table]
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

SELECT *
FROM 
(
SELECT
[from],
[Year],
[FX]
FROM [Reporting].[dbo].[FX_Table] WHERE [To] = 'Euro'
GROUP BY
[from],
[Year],
[FX]
) AS S
PIVOT
(
SUM(FX)
FOR [year] IN ' + @Cols + '
)
AS PVT
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT [from],
        [Year],
        [FX]
    FROM [Reporting].[dbo].[FX_Table]
    WHERE [To] = 'Euro'
    GROUP BY [from],
        [Year],
        [FX]
    ) AS S
PIVOT(SUM(FX) FOR [year] IN (
            SELECT DISTINCT year
            FROM [Reporting].[dbo].[FX_Table]
            )) AS PVT
```

You don't have to create a variable where you will store all your values and then try to use `IN` to go over those values and filter them.

Also, if you create a `NVARCHAR` variable to hold all your years, then you will have to split all those values, by comma, to use them with `IN` (which would make your declaration of variable `@Cols` useless).

What you will have in your `@Cols` variable, the way you create it now, is something like below (ONE record which is the list of years):

[image]

But for your `IN` clause to work, you would need multiple records, each year a new record, like below:

[image]

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you Radu, I think this is alot closer, but I am still getting the errors. from the select distinct quotename (year) and As PVT

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: Both the top and bottom of the pivot works fine. but for some reason just has that error- strange

Comment: @user3655574 Actually, it was correct the first time, with two parenthesis before `AS PVT`, at the end. The query that is in my answer now is syntactically corect. Please try.

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 14 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 16 Incorrect syntax near ')'. - same as the previous, I cant see what changed though

Comment: @user3655574 Try now. I had to remove the quotename.

Comment: Still getting the issue, the fact that the in only reads data bracketed by [ ] may be the issueMsg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: @user3655574 Have you tried removing the `Quotename()` function?

Comment: @user3655574 Can you try copy-pasting the code here http://poorsql.com/ and see if you get an error?

Comment: Hi Radu, Do you mean to copy your above script and paste it into the box which says input SQL in the link?

Comment: @user3655574 No, copy the script that you use there and then once you go to Formatted SQL you will get a warning if your query is not syntactically correct. I can't see where you're getting the error from.

Comment: I have done that, didnt alert me on any issue, I am using TSQL on microsoft SQL server Management studio, this is frustrating I am reporting this as a bug to microsoft

Comment: @user3655574 This is strange. Can you make a sqlfiddle.com with some sample data? A row or two from the tables you're using. I can look over it.